# Загрузка картинки в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Во всех справочниках и даже в официальной документации сказано, что вызов такого метода не должен вызывать ошибку:

```
Image hourglass = new Image("hourglass.jpg");
```

Но у меня вылетает:

```
Invalid URL or resource not found
```

Если добавляю вместо пути к картинке URL, то картинка нормально отображается. Не понимаю в чем дело. Исходник [тут](https://github.com/Faoxis/DemoJavaFx/blob/master/src/main/java/com/faoxis/javafx/book1/chapter35/ImageDemo.java). Картинка на всякий случай там же.

Answer (score 1):

В [официальной документации для класса Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) определены следующие конструкторы:

> **Image(java.io.InputStream is)** Construct an Image with content loaded from the specified input stream.
>
> **Image(java.io.InputStream is, double requestedWidth, double requestedHeight, boolean preserveRatio, boolean smooth)** Construct a
>   new Image with the specified parameters.
>
> **Image(java.lang.String url)** Constructs an Image with content loaded from the specified url.
>
> **Image(java.lang.String url, boolean backgroundLoading)** Construct a new Image with the specified parameters.
>
> **Image(java.lang.String url, double requestedWidth, double requestedHeight, boolean preserveRatio, boolean smooth)** Construct a
>   new Image with the specified parameters.
>
> **Image(java.lang.String url, double requestedWidth, double requestedHeight, boolean preserveRatio, boolean smooth, boolean
>   backgroundLoading)** Construct a new Image with the specified
>   parameters.

Используя следующий синтаксис:

```
Image hourglass = new Image("hourglass.jpg");
```

вы подразумеваете, что в **корневом** каталоге проекта находится файл `hourglass.jpg`. Файл же там не присутствует (судя по git-репозиторию) а находится глубже в дереве папок.

Comment: Нет, все правильно было с путями, надо было только добавить "file:/" к пути.  Все заработало, но я так и не понял почему.

Comment: @faoxis с путями похоже ошибка как раз и была...Магию в ваш код прносит не обявление схемы file:  а как раз добавление одинарного слеша после [прочтите](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView imageView= new ImageView(new image("file:путь к файлу");
Button button= new Button("Click me",imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Image image = new Image("hourglass.jpg");
ImageView img = new ImageView(image);
pane.getChildren().add(img);
```

У Вас картинка должна располагаться рядом с классом еще.

Comment: не работает вообще